# How to fetch data from DB send response back in PHP?

Tags: php, android, sql, sqlite

Need to take the `subject` provided by the user via android app and then use it to search database to find a `teacher` `name` and `email` for that `subject` and then send their `email`, `name` to android list view.

PHP Code:

```
 if ( !empty($_GET['subject']) ) {

    $SUBJECT=$_GET['subject'];
    $sql="SELECT IFF(sub== Name,Email,subjects_known FROM teacher_registration";
    $res=$con->query($sql);
    $result["Email"] = array();
    $result["Name"] = array();
    $result["Sub"] = array();
    $row=array();
    if($res->num_rows>0){
    while($row=$res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        //$Name= array();
        $Name= $row['Name'];
        //array_push($result["Name"], $Name);
       // $Email=array();
        $Email= $row['Email'];
        $Sub=$row['subjects_known'];
        array_push($result["Email"],$Email);
        array_push($result["Name"], $Name);
        array_push($result["Sub"],$Sub);

            // $result[] = $row;
     }
    // $r1=array();
    // $r1['TEACHER']=$result;
     echo json_encode($result,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
     mysqli_close($con);
  }
  else
  {
      echo "Give the info";
      mysqli_close($con);
  }
```

adapter

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;

import android.widget.TextView;



public class CustomListView extends BaseAdapter {


    public String[] profilename;
    public String[] Email;


    LayoutInflater li;


    public CustomListView(String[] p,String[] e,Teacher_searching ref) {
        Context context = ref;
        li=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.profilename=p;
        this.Email=e;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Email.length;

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return (position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override

    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder v=null;
        if(convertView==null){
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
            v=new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(v);
        }
        else {
            v=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        }

        v.tvw1.setText(profilename[position]);
        v.tvw2.setText(Email[position]);



        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{

        TextView tvw1;
        TextView tvw2;


        ViewHolder(View v){
            tvw1=v.findViewById(R.id.tvprofilename);
            tvw2=v.findViewById(R.id.tvemail);

        }

    }


}
```

search initiator:

```
public class Teacher_searching extends AppCompatActivity {
    String urladdress="https://light-headed-nests.000webhostapp.com/proed/searching1.php";
    String[] name;
    String[] Email;
    String SUBJECT_SEARCH;
    ListView listView;
    BufferedInputStream is;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    String subject_Search;
    String line;
    String result=null;
    Bundle b=new Bundle();

    JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    RequestQueue mqueue;
    StringRequest s;
    Integer i;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_teacher_searching);
        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lview);
        SUBJECT_SEARCH=b.getString("Teacher");
    //    collectData();
        mqueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
      jsonParse();
      //  onlyvolley();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Email.length,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*CustomListView customListView=new CustomListView(name,Email,Teacher_searching.this);
        listView.setAdapter(customListView);*/
    }

   /* private void onlyvolley() {
        s=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, urladdress,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        showMsg("Server Response","Page not reachable");
                    }
        )

    }*/

   private void jsonParse() {
        jsonObjectRequest=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urladdress, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONArray jsonArray=response.getJSONArray("TEACHER");
                            jsonObj=null;
                            name=new String[jsonArray.length()];
                            Email=new String[jsonArray.length()];
                            for (int i=0;i<=jsonArray.length();i++)
                            {
                                jsonObj=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                name[i]=jsonObj.getString("Name");
                                Email[i]=jsonObj.getString("Email");
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params=new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("subject",SUBJECT_SEARCH);
                return params;
            }
        };
        mqueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    /*private void collectData() {

        try{

            URL url=new URL(urladdress);
            HttpURLConnection con=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            subject_Search=b.getString("Teacher");
            jsonObj.put("subject",subject_Search);
            is=new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {}

        //content
        try{
            InputStreamReader read=new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(read);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while ((line=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

//JSON
        try{
            JSONArray ja=new JSONArray("TEACHER");
            JSONObject jo;
            name=new String[ja.length()];
            Email=new String[ja.length()];
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist =new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            for(i=0;i<=ja.length();i++){
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jo=ja.getJSONObject(i);
                name[i]=jo.getString("Name");
                Email[i]=jo.getString("Email");

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/
}
```

searchin for::

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Search_teacher extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner sub;
    Button btn;
    String sub_search[]={"Physics","Chemistry","Mathematics","Biology","English","Computer(C++)","Computer(Java)","History&Civics","Geography","Economics"};
    String Sub_stud;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_teacher);
        sub=findViewById(R.id.subject_search);
        btn=findViewById(R.id.btn);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,sub_search);
        sub.setAdapter(adapter2);
        sub.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                if(i==0)
                    Sub_stud="Physics";
                else if(i==1)
                    Sub_stud="Chemistry";
                else if(i==2)
                    Sub_stud="Mathematics";
                else if(i==3)
                    Sub_stud="Biology";
                else if(i==4)
                    Sub_stud="English";
                else if(i==5)
                    Sub_stud="Computer(C++)";
                else if(i==6)
                    Sub_stud="Computer(Java)";
                else if(i==7)
                    Sub_stud="History&Civics";
                else if(i==8)
                    Sub_stud="Geography";
                else if(i==9)
                    Sub_stud="Economics";
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void subject_teacher_search(View view) {
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Teacher_searching.class);
        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("Teacher",Sub_stud);
        i.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(i);

    }
}
```

stuff in list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvprofilename"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvemail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

the listview

```
<?xml version="1.

0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Teacher_searching"
    android:orientation="vertical">



        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>




</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Share your table description too. Without having a look into it, won't be able to tell if SELECT query is right or not.

Comment: Don't need to see the table schema to know there's some major syntax errors in that select... and why is this tagged sqlite when it looks like you're using mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a "**sql syntax error**" in your php code, anyway first resolve it appropriately and start doing the following steps in the application

Step-1: Create a request queue using "**Volley Library**" to retrieve json response from server

Step-2: Add a **"Custom_Listview"** in your layout file

Step-3: Finally set the "**Adapter Class**" to the listview.. That's it

[Follow the example](https://www.android-examples.com/volley-json-parsing-listview/)

Happy Coding!!

Comment: post your db structure i'll help you out!!